# Database design - One to many

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have to design a db (MySQL) where one record is associated to many.

For example:

> Record <-> Tags ( Persons(A,B,C...)  , Jobs(X,Y,Z...) , Areas(1,2,3 ...) )

Which way do you think is the best way to do it?

Comment: You need to explain your structure a little more clearly. You have what appear to be 3 table types nested inside `Tags`?

Comment: No homework ... 40 years old here LOL :)

Comment: Well , I'll try to explain better , but english is not my first language ... :P

Comment: I have a record ( address for example ) that is related to people ( bill , mary and joe ) , their jobs are programmer,cook and student living is somecity somewhere . I want to save the info to get the address searching for name+job , or name+area , or name1+name2 ...

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid anomalies ( on update and delete operations) you should normalize your relation. So I think you should do like that:

- Areas(areaId, personId,...)
  The same for jobs and other similar relations.
  About normalization see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization